# Run custom ApplicationContextInitializer in @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

i try to run a custum `ApplicationContextInitializer` within an integration test which is annotated with `@SpringBootTest`. I've tried to use a combination of `@SpringBootTest` and `@ContextConfiguration`, which looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(
    initializers = CustomContextInitializer.class
)
public class Test {
  ....
}
```

This fails because some bean construction triggered by `@SpringBootTest`, depends on properties which will be injected by programmaticaly logic of my `CustomContextInitializer` and this one is executed parallel so that this properties aren't available at this point.

Is there a solution for this situation? Could the `CustomContextInitializer` run before the initalisation procedure triggered by `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: There is a `TestPropertySource` for spring (boot) tests that you can use to configure your properties for tests.

Comment: Can you show a more detailed example of code? if you just want to set property before test execution then `TestPropertySource`  is a right solution, but if you need to run some dynamic logic before starting an application then it doesn't help you.